# ' Str object has no attribute "Crop" - Crop multible images using PIL and Tesseract

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have a folder with mutiple images. I want to crop all images with the same ratio, extract text and save into a list.But when I run these codes

```
    import glob
    image_list = []
    for filename in glob.glob('data5\*.jpg'):
      image=image_to_string( Image.open(filename))
      print(filename)
      crop=image.crop((20,10,320,70))
      print(crop)
      crop.save('data5\filename.jpg')
      b=image_to_string( Image.open('filename.jpg'), lang = 'deu' )
      image_list.append(b)
```

I got this error

```
     AttributeError   Traceback (most recent call 
   last)
   <ipython-input-199-e09f06845609> in <module>()
  4     image=image_to_string( Image.open(filename))
  5     print(filename)
  ----> 6     crop=image.crop((20,10,320,70))
  7     print(crop)
  8     crop.save('data5\filename.jpg')
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'crop'
```

Could you guys please help me fix this issue
`

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your image to a string object. How do you expect to crop a string? Just avoid using `image_to_string`.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps

img = Image.open(filename)
crop = ImageOps.crop(img, (10, 50, 35, 55))
```

This should work

Comment: Thank you very much .I can crop all images but when i want to save them ,I use this code :  crop.save('data6\filename.jpg') ,I got this error :OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'data6\x0cilename.jpg'. My filenames are : 00000 ,00025,00050... Do you know how I can save them with these names in another folder

Comment: You are saving with the same name in the same folder. Try a different folder like `data6` : `pic.save('data6\filename.jpg')
`

Comment: I modified it ,but I alway get this error : [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'data6\x0cilename.jpg' . It can not replace the name .

Comment: @Rive11 `filename` returns the entire path. Use `crop.save(os.path.join('data6', filename.split('/')[-1]))`. Before that import the library os `import os`

Comment: I can save it.But something 's weird happen . when I just apply my ratio for cropping one image A ,it returns the whole text ('Neuer Anlauf\nfür Verbotsverfahren .').But when I apply for the whole folder , this ratio cant return cropped -A  like when I do it seperately . It just returns 'Neuer Anlauf\nfür Verbotsverfa\n\no * .I mean do the ratio change when I apply the ratio for the whole folder ?

Comment: One problem is that I want to extract topics in this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyTtHdKWS2o ). I mean when the presenter mentions a new topic , this topic appears on the screen ( for eg , 00:19 , 06:33,... )and I want to extract them.But the problem is that , the topics are displayed around the same position , not exactly. I opened all the image ,try and pick up one ratio , manually . Then I apply this ratio for the whole images And of course ,this ratio isnt correct t for some images and some texts are lost .Are there way that I can extract the whole text for every images?.

Comment: Every time you keep asking something different! First you wanted to crop images, then you wanted to save them and now you want extract from a video? I think the answer to your initial question has been answered. If you have another question ask another one  with a link to this question.

Comment: I am really sorry . I just think you are an expert with issue and keep asking again again .I will post another topic .Thanks for your time .I really appreciate it

Comment: @Rive11 there is no need to be sorry. It's always good to clarify things. If textual region is what you want to crop, I would suggest using OCR from the tesseract library and use the resulting bounding box to crop your image

Comment: After I crop "Image", I use "image_to_string" to extract the text ( from pytesseract import image_to_string) .So  maybe this way is not effective . I tried your suggestion now .But I am beginner with this issue so could you please send me the link that you think can be useful . I really appreciate and sorry because I take much of your time.

Comment: @Rive11 `image_to_string` will detect the text in the image and return the text as a string. If you want to crop the textual region you must find another way